# Connecting VB.NET 2015 app to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

How do I connect MySQL database to a VB.NET 2015 application?

Comment: Download the [MySql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), add a reference to the dll, use ADO.NET similar to connecting with MS SQL-Server: `using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("connStr")){....}`

Comment: If you are asking literally for the connection string (hard to tell with such a vague question) see http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/  see also [Ask]

Comment: Thank you @TimSchmelter it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to connect to MySQL Database, you need to ensure below things:-

1. MySQL Connector is installed
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
2. Define connection string as Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

Or consult following link to suit your situation http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

3. Rest is same as you work MSSQL or OleDB connections.